# Why does the area function of a parallelogram have a nonintuitive geometric solution?

Tags: plane-geometry

I was reading a blog post on [a simple derivation of the cross product](http://behindtheguesses.blogspot.com/2009/04/dot-and-cross-products.html).  I learned how to determine the area of a [parallelogram enclosed by two vectors $A$ and $B$](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_D1sP-NndkqU/SfDq13JeaCI/AAAAAAAAHHc/Q_IyEv4AXkY/s1600-h/cross.gif).

First, here is the [proof](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_D1sP-NndkqU/SfDq4A_2oSI/AAAAAAAAHHk/lWBYwv6Mh4s/s1600-h/decomp.gif) of the solution ($area = A_x B_y - B_x A_y$)

And here's the [geometric implication](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_D1sP-NndkqU/SfDrt4Z-ZEI/AAAAAAAAHHs/yYqx4O3SCjQ/s1600-h/3dvec.gif) of the solution.

It bewilders me that the geometric solution is simple but nonintuitive.

One commenter (Tim Poston) on the blog offered an explanation by using the following lemma, which he states can be easily shown using elementary plane geometry, without the use of right angles or base*height to find areas:

$C(u+w,v) = C(u,v) + C(w,v)$

where $u, v, w$ are arbitrary vectors, and $C$ is the area function of the parallelogram between 2 vectors.

Here's my illustration of an [example implication of this lemma](https://i.imgur.com/RleJK.png) (visually simplified to triangles without loss of generality)

I was unable to prove this lemma, so I couldn't follow the argument.  Any thoughts or direction with this lemma or the original problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Warning: what you call "area" and "area function" refers to $\textit{oriented}$ area. Also, I hardly think this is "research level mathematics".

Comment: The pictures linked in this post seem to be dead. (I was able to find only one of them [in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506170111/https://i.imgur.com/XDLAO.gif).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to see this property if you stay with parallelograms and use the Cavalieri Principle. Here is [page](http://matematica-para-todos.wikispaces.com/Propriedade+de+Determinante+por+Cavalieri) with an animation showing what I mean (clink on the link and accept).

There is also a demonstration of the first formula using triangles and again using only Cavalieri. There was an animation "proof without words" for it in the site "art of problem solving" but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: Thanks, Cavalieri Principle was the key.  I found the animation you were talking about: http://www.usamts.org/Images/Side9.swf

Comment: The link to `matematica-para-todos.wikispaces.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot on the Wayback Machine of the specific page that is linked, though [some pages](https://web.archive.org/web/20120515000000*/http://matematica-para-todos.wikispaces.com/) may have been saved.

Answer (score 3):

Draw a triangle with sides given by the vectors u, w, u+w. Draw three identical vectors v with their tails at the three corners of the triangle. Draw a new triangle with corners at the heads of the vectors. The total area of your figure can be seen as two parallelograms plus a triangle, but it can also be seen as a third parallelogram plus a congruent triangle.